# How to hide mount binds in nautilus (not fstab)

Tags: mount, nautilus, bind

When I do a

```
mount --bind /A /B
```

via a bash-script a Bookmark entry in nautilus appears for each mount.

**They are not helpful and I want them to disappear. How do I do that?**

I read about an option when this is done via etc/fstab, but that doesn't seem to apply here.